# Is is possible to add Firebase to an iOS project from another framework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I´m trying to add Firebase to an iOS project. This project have a custom Framework on my iOS project. And I want to install firebase in that custom Framework. Do you think that it could give me a hard time on the future to have firebase on a separated framework? also in the case of crashlytics and analytics I´m only going to see the crash and analytics of this framework and not of the whole app ?

I´ve tried installing firebase and suceeded but failed when trying to test events, and seing analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is a set of static library frameworks. Therefore, it does not work to link Firebase into a dynamic framework.  Firebase can be linked into other static frameworks.

**Update 2024:** With the exception of Analytics, Firebase is distributed as source via CocoaPods and Swift Package Manager and can be build either static or dynamic frameworks.

Firebase 11 due out later in 2024 plans to change Analytics to dynamic as well. Tracked at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8945